# How to write the equations of the path to a point in complex numbers?

Tags: complex-numbers, polar-coordinates

I am given an arbitrary point G=a+ib and A(+1 in real axis), how can I write the walk from the G to the point A?

Comment: Not sure what you are after, especially given the tag "polar-coordinates".  The line segment $(1-t)G+tA$ for $t\in [0,1]$ starts at $G$, at $t=0$ and ends up at $A$ when $t=1$.  Is that what you wanted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

If the red vector is $\color{red}{G = a+ib}$ and the blue vector is $\color{blue}{A = 1+i0 = 1}$, then the green vector can be described as $\color{green}{G - A = a+ib-(1+i0) = (a-1)+i(b-0)=(a-1)+ib}.$

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I needed!

Comment: I'm glad for that! It's just a simple "vecor addition", like: blue + green = red. That means green = red - blue. See for example here: https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/vectors.html

Answer (score 0):

The path could be parametrized as $$z=G+t(1-G)=a+bi+t(1-a-bi)$$ where $$0\le t\le1$$